# sorting a dictionary in descending order of (i) keys (ii) Values in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 7}
```

If I want to sort in in descending order of **VALUES**, I use:

```
for w in sorted(dict_test, key=dict_test.get, reverse=True):
        print(w, dict_test[w])
```

What should I do for descending order of **KEYS**?

Comment: Could you provide an example of expected output?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! If any of the answers below have solved your question, please accept the best answer by checking the tick below the arrows next to the question, this helps close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close actually, just remove your `.get` method and you won't even need to pass a `key`.

```
dict_test = {1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 7}

for w in sorted(dict_test, reverse = True):
        print (w, dict_test[w])

>>
3 7
2 4
1 6
```

If you loop over just `dict_test` you are returned its keys and with `reverse = True`, you are returned with the keys in a descending order.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a dictionary doesn't have any real "order".

But you can get the keys as a list and sort this list.

```
sorted(dict_test.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehention which is fast and compact:

```
test_dict = {1: 6, 2: 4, 3: 7}

new_test_dict = {i: j for i,j in sorted(test_dict.items(), reverse=True)}
print(new_test_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Documents>py test.py
{3: 7, 2: 4, 1: 6}
```